# How do I use a command in an if statement in a Terminal Script on mac?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, finder

I am trying to write a script that will toggle between showing and hiding hidden files in Finder, but I'm having trouble with an error:

> ./HiddenFileToggle: line 1: [defaults: command not found

```
if [defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles]
then
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
else
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE
fi
killall Finder
```

Comment: See [this page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27428/what-does-backquote-backtick-mean-in-bash?newreg=04de89d7b4ca4d63b6d2ab93d88a44a4) for further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose the command in backticks `` ` ``:

```
`defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles`
```